# Change scrollbar in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Hi' Im making a large screen touch interface (ca 50 "). I have done user tests and found out that the scroll bars need to be like those that are in mobile applications so that users are forced to scroll by scrolling the "content" instead of doing it like in a wimp interface holding and draging the scrollbar with your finger which is rather difficult.

Now to my question, is it possible to style the scrollbars in html/css applications so that they appear as scrollbars in mobile applications (See image)[image]?

Im planning to run my touch application under windows 7 in a chrome web browser set to kiosk mode.

Comment: Yes this is possible. By making your own scroll bar and using `overflow:hidden` to avoid the default showing up. [here's an example in the wild](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)

Comment: hope this [plugin](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) help you. and this is easy to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use nanobar fot this
It a good plugin for generate beauty scroll bar on browser

https://github.com/jamesflorentino/nanoScrollerJS

or

http://www.mnking.net/2013/04/how-to-change-browser-scrollbar-in-html.html

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention Chrome, you can style the scrollbar natively with CSS rules - see [**Custom Scrollbars in WebKit**](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/)